# How to switch website language in VB.NET Web.Form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, routes, request.querystring

I have a simple website with two languages, english and french. In my master page, I have an hyperlink that switch to other language. When the user click on that hyperlink, I want to generate the URL exactly like Microsoft.com do! Thats mean:

1. http://www.microsoft.com/**fr-ca**/locale.aspx
2. http://www.microsoft.com/**en-us**/locale.aspx

And to do this, I'm a little confused! I register somes routes to do that but I don't know where I dynamicly switch the querystring variable to achieve that.

Here my RegisterRoutes from Application_Start in Global.asax:

```
Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)

    Dim language As String = "en-us"

    routes.MapPageRoute("Home", "home/{language}/{ReturnUrl}", "~/Default.aspx", True, 
        New RouteValueDictionary(New With {.language = language, .ReturnUrl = "default.aspx"}))

    routes.MapPageRoute("DetailsUser", "info-user/{language}/{id}", "~/DetailUsager.aspx", True,
        New RouteValueDictionary(New With {.language = language, .id = ""}))

    routes.MapPageRoute("Contact", "contact-us/{language}", "~/ContactForm.aspx", True,
        New RouteValueDictionary(New With {.language = language}))

    routes.MapPageRoute("SwitchLanguage", "{language}", "~/Home.aspx", True,
        New RouteValueDictionary(New With {.language = language}))
End Sub
```

I know this is a basic question but I don't find any answer about it. So what is the good way to made this done?

Thank again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The following code will get the language from the user request/browser header (en-US)

VB.Net

```
For Each s As String In Me.Request.UserLanguages
    Response.Write(s)
Next
```

C#

```
foreach (string s in this.Request.UserLanguages) {
    Response.Write(s);
}
```

The current language is the first one in the array:

VB.Net

```
Me.Request.UserLanguages(0)
```

C#

```
this.Request.UserLanguages[0]
```

Hope this answers it.
Thanks